# Bootstrap affix fullscreen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullscreen, floating, affix

I want to do this:

[image: sceenshot] "screen"

I have page in Boostrap and it is working great. I would like to add floating left div over page. So this is not dependend on content, but its over content. So basically I need CSS position: absolute with dynamic top.

I try many tips, but nothing works. I tried add affix.js before #wrap content, but on scroll content going under affix.

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Also, if you want that DIV to be always on top, have you checked z-index?

Comment: It's mean when I scrolling - Affix div cointainer get "position: relative" and it's break rest of page. With "position:fixed" it's ok, but I guess relative is needed for moving affix, when scrolling.

Looks like this, when scroll:
[screenshot](http://imgur.com/J5GVYBH)

Cause with position relative put content under affix.